# Looking for an Elko County Nevada Land Ownership Shapefile

Tags: data, united-states

I am looking for a Nevada Land Ownership shapefile.

County and state GIS don't seem to have anything beyond pdf.

Are there any public or commercial avenues to acquire land ownership in Nevada?

I'm really just needing public vs. private info.

Comment: For open data the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PolyGeo It is advisable to keep geospatial questions on-site rather than recommending an off-site solution. The following GIS meta post shows significant support for encouraging keeping data requests on-site: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4155/8104

Comment: @Aaron That Meta Q&A was about whether such questions should be migrated and since that time such questions have only been migrated at the request of their asker.  There were more votes for those saying open spatial data questions should be asked here rather than at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange but the only answer that provided SEDE-backed rather than anecdotal evidence demonstrated that open spatial data questions fare better when asked at [opendata.se] than here.  Consequently, I think we do a disservice to Stack Exchange users if we do not alert them to [opendata.se].

Answer (score 0):

Usually the BLM has a good public ownership layer since they manage the most public lands. You can try the [BLM Navigator](https://navigator.blm.gov/home) site--specifically [BLM NV Surface Management Agency (SMA) Polygons](https://navigator.blm.gov/data?keyword=6a843870b6565372)
.

> Description: The SMA dataset was created to display the management
>   status of the land through the BLM Administrative State of Nevada. In
>   2010 it was updated to be coincident with GCDB lines from Premier
>   data. The ownership for each smallest division was identified by the
>   previous land status layer. In areas of confusion or pieces that were
>   divided in areas smaller then GCDB, the MTP was referenced as the
>   final authoritative source. This project was completed 8/10/10, and is
>   updated as necessary. Updates have not occurred to bring the dataset
>   into alignment with the most current CadNSDI PLSS data and there are
>   known alignment errors.